# C# ServerManager leaking memory on Windows 7

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, windows-7-x64

I have been trying to diagnose a memory leak in a service which only appears on Windows 7/Server 2008 R2. I narrowed it down to where we are using Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager to gather info about the apps in our site. I whittled it down to the console app below, which exhibits the same behavior. It might still be more complex than it needs to be, but I wanted to emulate the behavior of the service as much as possible.

I found a previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11509902/microsoft-web-administration-memory-leak) that was very similar and made the changes suggested in the answers. This appeared to reduce the rate of growth, but it still leaks significantly (under the comments "Original Test" I have commented out code that I changed based on those answers. the "Modified Test" comments indicate the changes I made. I didn't initially have the GC.Collect call in, and when I ran this on a Windows 10 system, it grew for quite some time before the garbage collection kicked in. With the GC.Collect call in place, it ran without growing on Win 10, but on Win 7 it made no difference.

I ran it under a profiler that indicated the memory being leaked was native, and that the leak was coming from nativerd.dll.

Has anyone encountered a problem like this? I'm new to C# and am still learning how Garbage Collection works, so I'm wondering if there is something I'm doing wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Web.Administration;

namespace ServerManagerLeakTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Working.");
            var me = new MyClass();
            me.Run();
        }
    }

    internal class MyClass
    {
        ServerManagerWrapper _smw = new ServerManagerWrapper();

        public void Run()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var t = Task.Run(async delegate
                {
                    DoWork();
                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                });
                try
                {
                    t.Wait();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.Write("Main Exception: " + e.Message);
                }
                Console.Write(".");
            }
        }
        public void DoWork()
        {
            try
            {
                var data = _smw.GetWebApps().ToList();
                data.Clear();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.Write("DoWork Exception: " + e.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    internal class ServerManagerWrapper
    {
        public List<int> GetWebApps()
        {
            List<int> result = new List<int>() { };

            // Original Test
            //
            // using (var serverManager = new ServerManager())
            // {
            //     foreach (var site in serverManager.Sites)
            //     {
            //         result.AddRange(GetWebApps(site));
            //    }
            //}

            // Modified Test
            var serverManager = new ServerManager();
            foreach (var site in serverManager.Sites)
            {
                result.AddRange(GetWebApps(site));
            }
            serverManager.Dispose();
            serverManager = null;
            System.GC.Collect();

            return result;
        }

        private IEnumerable<int> GetWebApps(Site site)
        {
            // Original Test
            //
            //for (var application in site.Applications)
            //{
            //    yield return application.GetHashCode();
            //}

            // Modified Test
            List<int> result = new List<int>() { };
            for (int i = 0; i < site.Applications.Count; i++)
            {
                result.Add(site.Applications[i].GetHashCode());
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Microsoft.Web.Administration is just a wrapper over `nativerd.dll`. It was designed for IIS Manager and appcmd by default, and both are short lived tools you fire and close (so small leaks won't matter usually). What kind of application are you working on that memory leak is critical to you?

Comment: It's a service which, among other things, is checking for the existence of applications within a our site. It is doing this check every 30 seconds.

Comment: Move the check to a separate process. Calling IIS REST API, PowerShell, or even appcmd and parse the result. Let the leak be out of your own service.

Comment: @Lex Li: this is a very pragmatic way, but probably the quickest and perhaps the only solution. I know most developers don't like the idea of calling external processes, but I've been in similar situations. And I know of at least one MS COM API (FSRM FCI) where even MS calls out to an external exe (at least in the first version of FCI, which was painfully slow...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer provided in comments from @Lex Li.

> Move the check to a separate process. Calling IIS REST API, PowerShell, or even appcmd and parse the result. Let the leak be out of your own service.